# How to show my data in plain text in paragraph which is wrapped in JSON text using Jquery?

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, json, jsp

I'm new in JSON. I'm using Coinbase API which is wrapped in `JSON`.

Have a look into this code:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"%> 
<%@ page import="rajendra.arora.bitcoin.CoinbaseExample" %>  

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>This is foo.</h1>
<p>This is my Amount balance in Coinbase:</p>
<%
    CoinbaseExample ce=new CoinbaseExample();
    String myBal=ce.getHttp("https://api.coinbase.com/v1/account/balance", null);
%>

<p id="demo">
    <%
        out.print(myBal);
    %>
</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Which shows my ***Output*** as follows:

> This is foo.
>
> This is my Amount balance in Coinbase:
>
> {"amount":"0.00000000","currency":"BTC"}

I know this is in JSON wrapped. But can you please help me, how to show these data in normal form in `div` tag using Jquery?

***Can you please help me? How to show this in plain Text.***

***Surely, Help would be appreciated!!***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or maybe

```
<script>
var myBal = <% out.print(myBal); %>
document.write(myBal.amount);
// or document.write($.parseJSON(myBal.amount));
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your myBal is a String, maybe set it as a JSONObject like:

```
JSONOBject myBal=ce.getHttp("https://api.coinbase.com/v1/account/balance", null);
```

Then your output:

```
out.print(myBal.get("amount");
out.print(myBal.get("currency");
```

Hope this helps :)

In a div this will look like:

```
<div>
    <%
        out.print(myBal.get("amount");
        out.print(myBal.get("currency");
    %>
</div>
```

Comment: Do i need to download any jar files for JSON?

Comment: i'm note quite sure, but think this is standard functionality of jsp.

Comment: No, i'm just asking.. Do i need to download any jar file for JSON? Can you please tell me the link to download JSON jar?